# ¿Android Studio con Java, dónde está el fallo?

Tags: java, android-studio, app

No conozco el lenguaje Java, sólo quería hacer una pequeña aplicación en el entorno de *Android Studio*, muy sencilla, que hice con *Python*. **Al construir no me da ningún error**, pero en el emulador se cierra la aplicación, debe haber un fallo (o varios) lógico que el compilador (obviamente) no detecta.

El objetivo es que el usuario introduzca la cantidad de aceite y el tipo y que después de calcular las cantidades de sosa y agua a emplear, lo muestre en pantalla.

Gracias de antemano!!

Aquí va mi código:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.myapplication.R.id.txtsosa;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private double sosa,agua, c;
        private int aceite;


        public void oliva(View view){
             c = 0.134;
        }
        public void girasol(View view){
             c = 0.137;
        }
        public void calcular(View view){
            sosa = c*aceite;
            agua = 0.3*aceite;
        }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View cantidadAceite = findViewById(R.id.cantidad_aceite);
        Integer aceite = Integer.parseInt(cantidadAceite.toString());
        final TextView cantidadSosa = (TextView) findViewById(txtsosa);
        cantidadSosa.setText(String.valueOf(sosa));
        final TextView cantidadAgua = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtagua);
        cantidadAgua.setText(String.valueOf(agua));
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Aparece algún error o Excepción en los logs?

Comment: `final TextView cantidadSosa = (TextView) findViewById(txtsosa);`, txtsosa? Será R.id.txtsosa, supongo

Comment: Alguna respuesta te ha valido? Si es así, te invito a votar por la válida o a modificar tu pregunta si aún no la has resuelto y tienes más dudas sobre lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo tu código tienes declaradas las variables:

```
private double sosa,agua, c;
```

Que a primera instancia no tienen ningún valor asignado, pero en el método `onCreate()` que es el método encargado de ejecutarse cuando se inicia la actividad realizas los `setText()`:

```
cantidadSosa.setText(String.valueOf(sosa));
cantidadAgua.setText(String.valueOf(agua));
```

Con valores que en ningún momento asignaste, podrías probar comentando esas líneas de `setText()` para comprobar que el error es ese.

También podrías comentar la línea:

```
Integer aceite = Integer.parseInt(cantidadAceite.toString());
```

Ya que a un inicio `cantidadAceite` no tendrá ningún valor (A no ser que le hayas dado la propiedad text en el xml).

---

Hago referencia al método [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) para que le des una leída y veas que es lo que puedes poner en éste método:

> **onCreate():** Llamado cuando la actividad está comenzando. Aquí es donde debería ir la mayoría de las inicializaciones: llamar a setContentView (int) para inflar la interfaz de usuario de la actividad, usar findViewById (int) para interactuar mediante programación con los widgets en la interfaz de usuario, llamar a managedQuery (android.net.Uri, java.lang.String [], java.lang.String, java.lang.String [], java.lang.String) para recuperar cursores para los datos que se muestran, etc.

Saludos. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Este código no tiene sentido:

```
View cantidadAceite = findViewById(R.id.cantidad_aceite);
Integer aceite = Integer.parseInt(cantidadAceite.toString());
```

y obviamente te va a producir una excepción.

Estás obteniendo un objeto View desde el ID de algo que seguramente sea un `EditText` o algo así, y en la segunda línea estás haciendo el `tostring()` de ese objeto. Esto no te va a retornar el contenido del `EditText`, sino que te retornará una cadena con datos del objeto `View`. Si a eso le haces un `parseInt`, te saldrá una bonita excepción de parseo imposible.

Si tu elemento visual es un `EditText`, obtén un `EditText` y el texto contenido en él de esta forma:

```
EditText cantidadAceite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cantidad_aceite);
Integer aceite = 0;
try {
    aceite = Integer.parseInt( cantidadAceite.getText().toString());
} catch( Execption ex) {
}
```

El `try-catch` es importante porque si en el EditText escriben algo que no sea numérico, tu aplicación volverá a generar una excepción. Podrías mostrar un mensaje diciendo que el dato introducido es incorrecto o algo así.

Otra cosa: Inicializa las variables antes de usarlas o te llevarás sorpresas.
Y otra más: ¿Porqué las funciones que hacen los cálculos reciben un parámetro `View`? Si no van a hacer más que cálculos, no necesita ningún parámetro.

Comment: Si reciben un parámetro View imagino que es porque las ha enlazado directamente en el xml de la vista, cuando pones ahí la función que un componente dispara, debes pasarle un parámetro View para que Android Studio pueda hacer la asignación al componente

Comment: Efectivamente, para poder enlazarlos con los edit text y textview. Es un rollo usar edittext para tener un número con el que operar para luego volver a introducirlo como texto.